# ng update from 5.2.0 to 5.2.9 throws protractor ng e2e error "Failed: Angular could not be found on the page"

Tags: angular, protractor

From angular 5.2.0, my e2e tests were running properly.  An update to 5.2.9 gives me the error below.  I've tried increasing the protractor configurations for `allScriptsTimeout` and `getPageTimeout`, but it just increases the wait period before the error is thrown.

```
[06:50:19] E/protractor - Could not find Angular on page http://localhost:49152/ : retries looking for angular exceeded

  Landing Page
    ✗ should contain layout elements
      - Failed: Angular could not be found on the page http://localhost:49152/. If this is not an Angular application, you may need to turn off waiting for Angular.
                            Please see 
                            https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular-on-page-load
                            Please see 
                            https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular-on-page-load
      at executeAsyncScript_.then (/home/projects/node_modules/protractor/built/browser.js:720:27)
      at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/home/projects/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1376:14)
      at TaskQueue.execute_ (/home/projects/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3084:14)
      at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/home/projects/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3067:27)
      at asyncRun (/home/projects/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2927:27)
      at /home/projects/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:668:7
      at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
      From: Task: Run it("should contain layout elements") in control flow
      at UserContext.<anonymous> (/home/projects/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:94:19)
      at /home/projects/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:64:48
      at ControlFlow.emit (/home/projects/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/events.js:62:21)
      at ControlFlow.shutdown_ (/home/projects/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2674:10)
      at shutdownTask_.MicroTask (/home/projects/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2599:53)
      at MicroTask.asyncRun (/home/projects/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2728:9)
      at /home/projects/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:668:7
      at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
      From asynchronous test: 
      Error
      at Suite.<anonymous> (/home/projects/e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts:10:3)
      at Object.<anonymous> (/home/projects/e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts:3:1)
      at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
      at Module.m._compile (/home/projects/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:422:23)
      at Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
      at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/home/projects/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:425:12)
      at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
      at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
      at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
      at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
      at require (internal/module.js:11:18)

**************************************************
*                    Failures                    *
**************************************************

1) Landing Page should contain layout elements
  - Failed: Angular could not be found on the page http://localhost:49152/. If this is not an Angular application, you may need to turn off waiting for Angular.
                        Please see 
                        https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular-on-page-load

Executed 1 of 1 spec (1 FAILED) in 11 secs.
[06:50:19] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[06:50:19] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[06:50:19] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[06:50:19] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
```

Here are my package.json changes after ng update.  The keys were omitted for readability

```
"@angular/animations": "5.2.9",
"@angular/common": "5.2.9",
"@angular/compiler": "5.2.9",
"@angular/core": "5.2.9",
"@angular/forms": "5.2.9",
"@angular/http": "5.2.9",
"@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.9",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.9",
"@angular/router": "5.2.9",
"rxjs": "^5.5.10",
"zone.js": "^0.8.26",
"@angular/cli": "1.7.4",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.9",
"@angular/language-service": "5.2.9",
"typescript": "2.6.2"
```

Comment: That's not good. Several questions: 1. What version of ChromeDriver, Selenium-Server, Chrome are you using with this failure? 2. Did the Protractor version change between the upgrade? 3. What version of node are you running?

Comment: (1) Chrome is Version 65.0.3325.181 on Ubuntu 16.04 

(2) No. The protractor package was never updated. Only rxjs, zone.js and typescript were the non-angular updates

(3) Node is v8.11.1

Comment: Also protractor is at "protractor": "~5.1.2".  I did update it to the @latest package thinking it would fix it but no luck there.

Answer (score 0):

I updated to angular 6 and the protractor error is no longer thrown

---

Chrome: Version 66.0.3359.139
protractor: 5.3.0
angular: 6.0